# How do i fix android activity in a stable position?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm building a simple app for android that's taking input from the user via an EditText. But when the EditText is focused and the on screen keyboard appears it causes the whole layout to move a few dps so that the action bar slides under the statusbar. How can i fix the activity so that it doesn't move when the keyboard opens?

Tried this which made it better but it still moves a few dps
  View dv=getWindow().getDecorView();
  dv.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `adjustResize` as your activity's `android:windowSoftInputMode`. Add the following line in your manifest in that particular activity.

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

Also, check the other [options available for windowsSoftInputMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html).